# Javascript on click - two parts to the function but only one works at a time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two server side php scripts:
1: /addit.php - which creates a pdf file on server based on current ID given
2: /viewit.php - which downloads the pdf file to the browser window.

Both these scripts work fine btw. 
However I want to combine a single onclick function to run "addit.php" and then view the file by opening the file "view.php". 
So I am using the original code that was creating the file ok and then adding in a window.location but they won't work together. If I remove the window.location the first part of code works fine, If I include it, the first part stops working and only the window.location works.

Sorry for being stupid, thanks.

```
function download_invoice() {
    $(document).on('click','.downloadit',function(id){
        var current_element = $(this);
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var ida = $(this).attr('id')+"A";
        var idicon = $(this).attr('id')+"icon";

        $.post('myaddress/addit.php',
           { list_entry_id: id },
            $("#infobox_data_button2").fadeTo(1001,.33)
        );
    });

    window.location="myaddress/viewit.php";
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move `window.location="myaddress/viewit.php";` to ajax callback as below. Otherwise it fires before you get response from server.

```
$.post('myaddress/addit.php',
     { list_entry_id: id },
     function() {
        $("#infobox_data_button2").fadeTo(1001,.33);
        window.location="myaddress/viewit.php";
     }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The window.location is out of the event. While you run the ajax (asynchronous) to 'myaddress/addit.php' the redirect will occur killing the process.

You need to put the window.location in a success callback, therefore in the event.

```js
function download_invoice() {
    $(document).on('click','.downloadit',function(id){
        var current_element = $(this);
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var ida = $(this).attr('id')+"A";
        var idicon = $(this).attr('id')+"icon";

        $.post('myaddress/addit.php', { list_entry_id: id }, function(data){
            $("#infobox_data_button2").fadeTo(1001,.33);
          
            // Here!
            window.location="myaddress/viewit.php";
        });
    });
    // Abandoned
    //window.location="myaddress/viewit.php";
};
```